# on a countably union of $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $F$ be a countably union of $F_\sigma$ sets, say $F_i$ for $i\in \mathbb N$. Is it true that if $F$ is not meager then there is an $F_i$ with non-empty interior? For me it's true but I can't find a strong argument to prove it. Thank you

Comment: A countable union of $F_{\sigma}$ sets is an $F_{\sigma}$ set :), as an $F_{\sigma}$ is a countable union of closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contradiction to prove it. 
If all $F_i$ are of empty interiors, then countable union of $F_i$ is meager.